# android xabber not authorizing openfire xmpp account

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire

I have downloaded xabber app from [play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xabber.android) in **mobile1**. I have successfully installed openfire xmpp server on my local machine and have created two users **testuser1** and **testuser2**. From xabber android app I have added account with zabberId **testuser1@192.168.1.1** and it is successfully added and showing online status.
  Now I have downloaded xabber app in  **mobile2**. I have added account with zabberId **testuser2@192.168.1.1** and it is successfully added and showing online status.

Now I am trying to add contact(testuser2@192.168.1.1) on mobile1 with testuser1@192.168.1.1 But the request is not sending to testuser2@mypc.

But the same thing works If I tested for gmail accounts.
What is the issue?

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution. I cannot add contact with ipaddress like testuser2@192.168.1.1 ,instead I have to use proper host name like testuser2@mypc. But to create account I have to use ipaddress like testuser2@192.168.1.1. Since I am working with locally installed openfire xmpp server , it is bit confusing with ipaddress and hostname